# Image Preview in own camera-- Android

Tags: android, layout, android-camera, preview

I'm doing an app, that needs the device(usually a tablet) to be in landscape, but the picture has to be shown in portrait in the screen.

Until here, I have done it. Bu now, when I take a picture the "preview" image, is showed in landsacape and looks very strange.

See image to see what I mean:

How you see before take image:
[image]

And thats after take picture:
[image]

And I don't know how to fix it

Thats surfaceView:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        // stop Preview Before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignored: is trying to stop a non-existent preview

        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CAMERAPREVIEW", "Error starting camera preview : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

And the method overrided

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

//                              Not used for the moment
//              Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
//              setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
//              finish();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Camera.setDisplayOrientaion()` to rotate the preview on the `SurfaceView`. But this does not effect the captured image. Your post does not reveal how you display the captured image from file (I assume this is what you show in the [second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmlo3.jpg)). If you load it as a bitmap into an `ImageView`, you can request rotation for the bitmap.

It also looks like your picture dimensions have different aspect ratio from the preview. I suggest that you look at a recent discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668394/camera-in-android-how-to-get-best-size-preview-size-picture-size-view-size).

But maybe I misunderstand what you are doing. Maybe your problem is that you don't restart preview in `onPicturetaken()`?