# Permission not asking for Updated apk in play store in android 6.0

Tags: java, android, google-play

**I already having app in play store.I recently added new apk in play store.
Previously i added 3 permissions for location,camera and contacts(i added in array format).**

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                        , android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        , Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                        , Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS
                        , Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                1000);
    }
```

now the latest one having set of 5 permission (location,camera,contacts,read sms,get accounts).but after updating old apk to new apk from play store. it is not asking permission in android 6.0.please give me some suggestion to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logical error. Use `||` instead of `&&`.

You have requested the permissions only if all permissions are denied. If at least one of them is denied, the permissions will not be requested.

To request permissions if any of the given permissions is not allowed, use `||`.

It looks like you are having trouble dealing with the runtime permissions. You can use my library to handle runtime permissions easily. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions